# I got error No hint path defined for error with diglactic breadcrumbs plugin?

Tags: laravel, breadcrumbs

In laravel 8, tailwindcss 2.1 app I want to add https://github.com/diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs
so on install I modified config/breadcrumbs.php with :

'view' => 'partials.breadcrumbs::tailwind',

and as I want to modify defalt colors reading doc I created
resources/views/partials/breadcrumbs.blade.php file with content from the description

I filled file routes/breadcrumbs.php with breadcrumbs definitions I need.
But I got error :

```
No hint path defined for [/partials.breadcrumbs]. 
(View: /MyProject/resources/views/admin/dashboard/index.blade.php)
```

Looks like some path is invalid, but I do not see what I missed ?

I cleared cache, but it did not not help!

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if I want to use and edit partial file  /MyProject/resources/views/admin/dashboard/index.blade.php, I have not to set tailwind in 'View' parameter , just :

```
  'view' => 'partials.breadcrumbs',
```

Comment: Right on! This package resolves a path the same way the Laravel `view('foo.bar')` function works. Feel free to open an issue directly on the repo if anything else comes up! https://github.com/diglactic/laravel-breadcrumbs